# Can a standard topological space be constructed from a closed subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

I have just started studying topological spaces. I am having trouble understanding the relationships between closed spaces. My question is:

> Can a standard toplogical space be constructed from $X$, a closed subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which includes all points in $X$?

**My Understanding**

*Definition of a Topological Space:* A topological space is an ordered pair $(X, T)$, where $X$ is a set and $T$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ which satisfy the following condition:

- $\emptyset,X\in T$ and $T$ is closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections.

I understand that the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $(\mathbb{R}^n,T)$, where $T$ is the set of all possible unions of open balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Similarly for the open set $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, a standard topology can be given by $(X,T_X)$, where $T_A$ is the set of all possible unions of open balls in $X$.

I do not understand the case where $X$ is a closed subset. Can I use the set of all closed subsets in $X$? Can I only use open sets to construct a topological space?

Comment: The subspace toplogy on $X$ is the set of all $X\cap Y$ where $Y$ is open in $\mathbf R^n$

Comment: The standard topology on $R^n$ are not the open balls, but all possible unions of open balls (the union of 2 balls isn't a ball). In other words, the open balls are a basis for the usual topology.

Comment: Sorry that is what I meant to say. I will correct that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction that you're looking for is called the *subspace topology.* Given a topological space $(Y, \tau)$, and set $A \subset Y$, the topology on $Y$ induces a topology $\tau_A$ on $A$ called the subspace topology of $Y$ on $A$ by the rule $$ V \in \tau_A \text{ if and only if } V = A \cap U \text{ for some } U \in \tau.$$ Regardless of the topological space $(Y, \tau)$ and subset $A$, this is in fact a topology. Sets $U \in \tau_A$ are called *relatively open* in $A$ with respect to $Y$, or just open in $A$ when it is understood that the subspace topology is being used. This is the standard way of introducing a topology on a subset of a space, and works without problem on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard topology.

Comment: Just so that I understand what you are saying is the following statement correct. If $X \subset R^n$ and $X$ is closed, $(X,T_X)$ is a topological space so long as $T_x\in T$, where $T$ is the set of all possible unions of open balls in $R^n$.

Comment: The topology $\tau_X$ should be formed by taking *intersections* of unions of open balls with $X$, not with original open balls. An important detail here is that the elements of our subspace topology will likely not all be elements of the original topology. For instance, if our subspace is taken on a proper closed set $X$, then $X$ will be *open* in the subspace topology in addition to closed.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing up my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to answer part of your question:

> I do not understand the case where $X$ is a closed subset. Can I use the set of all closed subsets in $X$? Can I only use open sets to construct a topological space?

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "use the set of all closed subsets": You can use them to tell you which sets *are* open; a set is "open" iff its complement is closed. So, if you have a list of all closed subsets of $X$, then the open sets in your topological space would be precisely the complements of these closed subsets in $X$.

You **don't** want to "use" closed subsets in the sense of forming a topological space as articulated in your definition. I'll come back to this point at the end.$^\star$

As an example, suppose $X = [0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ is the space in question. Here, the open sets would be exactly those that can be written in the form $U \cap X$ where $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open in the traditional sense.

**Example:** The set $(1/3, 2/3)$ is open in $X=[0,1]$ because we can use this set itself as the above-mentioned $U$ and observe that $U \cap X = U$. So $U = (1/3, 2/3)$ is open in $X$. Similarly, any *open set in* $\mathbb{R}$ that is contained entirely in $X$ is *also open in* $X$.

But there are other sets that are open with this "subspace topology" that were not open in $\mathbb{R}$.

**Example:** The set $[0, 1/2)$ is open in $X = [0,1]$. Note that this set is not open (nor is it closed, incidentally) in $\mathbb{R}$. But, it is open in our topological space whose set is $X$ with the subspace topology: specifically, we can write the set $[0, 1/2)$ as the intersection $(-1, 1/2) \cap X$. Since the set $(-1, 1/2)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, we have that $[0, 1/2) = (-1, 1/2) \cap X$ is open *in* $X$. (But not $\mathbb{R}$!)

$^\star$: You cannot just take closed subsets and declare them the open sets. For example, if you naively tried to use all closed subsets of $[0,1]$ to form a topology, you'd run into problems. For example, one of your requirements for a topological space is closure under arbitrary unions. But, the set formed by the union of closed sets

$$\bigcup_{n>1} [\frac{1}{n},\frac{n}{n+1}] = (0,1)$$

yields an open set, not a closed one; so, the idea of using only closed sets fails: it is not closed under arbitrary unions as demonstrated by this example in which an arbitrary union of closed sets yields a set that is *not* closed.

Comment: [More generally, if all closed sets are part of your topology i.e. open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then every set is open: This is because individual points are closed under the standard Euclidean topology, which would mean that the arbitrary union of individual points becomes open: but, every set can be written in this way. That is, $$A = \bigcup_{a \in A} a$$ is a fancy way of saying/writing, "the set $A$ is equal to the union of all the points in $A$."]